# Possible to generate UI runtime in Windows Store apps (Metro)?

Tags: reflection, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

We're currently researching if it is possible to on the fly generate/change the UI of a metro app. So far I have seen only that the reflection options are somewhat limited. But perhaps if we're using HTML/JS we can modify the HTML on the fly? Anybody tried something like this?

Will fire up VS later and give it a go, just thought I'd ask here and see if we could have a disucssion on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Javascript-based apps modify their HTML on the fly as this is a pattern promoted by the Navigator template. So for example even just clicking a link and navigating to another page will replace the content of a 'page' container element instead of reloading the whole page and thus reloading all .js and .css files.

Also the WinJS.UI.ListView will dynamically create and reposition elements in your DOM as you scroll its contents.

Basically you can do anything you'd do in a webapp and re-use patterns like known from AJAX to make your UI adapt dynamically.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you should with increasing complexity keep in mind that your app should be able to suspend and restore its state from scratch at any point.

Comment: Does this mean that I can get the actual HTML from the server and/or generate it on the fly on the client?

Comment: Yes, you can dynamically alter the HTML like with any JavaScript on a normal website. If you want to use content from a remote server, you can do that using various methods: iframe, replacing the innerHTML of one of your elements or parsing some file you download from a server and build new elements accordingly.